# MS Access & Microsoft SQL Server Date Format Problems

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I have an MS Access Applications where some fields are dates. On my testserver on my localmachine everything works great, but when i change the tables to the production server, the date formats change to american.
Is that a setting in the database I am missing? I searched all the options but I couldn't find a way to change it.
I also looked in Ms Access but I didnt see an option to change the dateformat.
All help is appreciated!

Ms Access Version is 2016.
My testserver is version 15 but the production server is version 12.

Comment: The `date` and `datetime` data types in SQL Server are binary values, they don't have a presentation format. How are you accessing the tables from Access? How are you presenting the information in the UI (Access forms)? It sounds like instead of using SQL Parameters that you may be using SQL Injection techniques to insert date/datetime values as strings into the middle of SQL queries.

Comment: As @AlwaysLearning mentions, date values carry no format. When displayed, a default format is applied which may or may not fit the user. If a certain format is required, specify that format where you plan to display the date/time values.

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for the replys. I access the tables via ODBC. I have a form with a textfield and I selected the date from the DB as the control source. Before I selected the control soruce, i had the textfield set to format "short date" and it worked, I had the german date format. But as soon as I set the control source, It didnt work anymore. I also dont have the datepicker next to the field.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. The problem was that i used an old ODBC driver and thus access didnt recognize the date field as a date but as a shortText. I resolved it by changing the type date to type datetime in the database.